# Wordpress — why stop wp_insert_post()?

Tags: wordpress

Trying to load 4.5 million records in wordpress.
Import stops at ~ 90 thousands. Why so?
If you remove the function wp_insert_post(), the cycle runs (89 times).
No errors in logs. Please help me

```
<?
require_once('../../wp-load.php');
$host='host';
$database='database';
$user='user';
$pswd='pswd';
$dbh = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pswd) or die("Не могу соединиться с MySQL.");
mysqli_select_db($dbh, $database) or die("Не могу подключиться к базе.");
for ($l = 0; $l <= 89; $l++) {
    $limit = $l * 50000;
    $sql = "SELECT `NPI`, `Provider_Last_Name_Legal_Name`, `Provider_First_Name`, `Provider_Middle_Name`, `Provider_Name_Prefix_Text`, `Provider_Name_Suffix_Text`, `Provider_First_Line_Business_Mailing_Address`, `Provider_Second_Line_Business_Mailing_Address`, `Provider_Business_Practice_Location_Address_City_Name`, `Provider_Business_Practice_Location_Address_State_Name`, `Provider_Business_Practice_Location_Address_Postal_Code`, `Provider_Business_Practice_Location_Address_Telephone_Number`, `Provider_Business_Practice_Location_Address_Fax_Number`, `Provider_Gender_Code`, `Provider_First_Line_Business_Practice_Location_Address` FROM `npi` WHERE `used` != 1 AND `Provider_Last_Name_Legal_Name` != ''  LIMIT ".$limit.", 50000";
    $res = mysqli_query($dbh, $sql);
    $i = 0;
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $post_title = $row['Provider_First_Name'] . ' ' . $row['Provider_Middle_Name'] . ' ' . $row['Provider_Last_Name_Legal_Name'];
        $defaults = array(
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_type' => 'doctor',
            'post_author' => 1,
            'post_title' => $post_title
        );
        /*
        $post_id = wp_insert_post($defaults, $wp_error);
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'npi_number', $row['NPI']);
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'provider_name_prefix_text', $row['Provider_Name_Prefix_Text']);
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'provider_name_prefix_text', $row['Provider_Name_Prefix_Text']);
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'provider_name_suffix_Text', $row['Provider_Name_Suffix_Text']);
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'provider_first_line_business_mailing_address', $row['Provider_First_Line_Business_Mailing_Address']);
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'provider_second_line_business_mailing_address', $row['Provider_Second_Line_Business_Mailing_Address']);
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'provider_business_practice_location_address_city_name', $row['Provider_Business_Practice_Location_Address_City_Name']);
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'provider_business_practice_location_address_state_name', $row['Provider_Business_Practice_Location_Address_State_Name']);
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'zip', $row['Provider_Business_Practice_Location_Address_Postal_Code']);
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'provider_business_practice_location_address_telephone_number', $row['Provider_Business_Practice_Location_Address_Telephone_Number']);
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'provider_business_practice_location_address_fax_number', $row['Provider_Business_Practice_Location_Address_Fax_Number']);
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'provider_gender_code', $row['Provider_Gender_Code']);
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'provider_first_line_business_practice_location_address', $row['Provider_First_Line_Business_Practice_Location_Address']);
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'is_npi', '1');
        */
        $i++;
        unset($post_title, $row, $post_id, $defaults);
    }
    echo 'Cycle: '.$l.'<hr>';
    unset($post_title, $row, $post_id, $defaults);
}
?>
```

Comment: You're looping 50k rows at a time, and doing a single insert for each... the problem is likely that your script is timing out, insert operations are slow.

Comment: How can I fix it? I increased the script execution time to 3 days, did not help

Comment: PHP will time out anytime you try to run something that long and data intensive. There simply is never enough resources allocated to PHP to do it not to mention the amount of queries happening on each pass. You are going to have to break it down into do-able chunks.

Comment: I broke 5000 and set a timeout after each cycle

Comment: I see an error mysql "query execution was interrupted"